# How to populate all custom options of a configurable product in product view?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a configurable product in magento which has a size and color as product options. But the colors options gets populated when I have selected a size.
Now I want to populate size and color before any options are selected.

```
$j("#attribute1051")[0].selectedIndex = 1;
$j( "#attribute1051" ).change();
```

I have tried to change values in configurable.js or tried to select a value through js, but then the config settings do not get reloaded.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

[I can recommend you an extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher) that among others does what you need.
It allows you to choose one of the simple products associated to configurable products to  be the default configuration selected when the page loads, or, if you don't set a simple product as default you can set the first combination available to be selected.
Extension documentation [can be found here](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/wiki)